# Two questions on number 2013

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

**a)** All natural numbers from $1$ to $2013$ are written in a row in an order. Can you insert '+' and '-' signs between them so that the value of the resulting expression is zero? If it is so how many '+' and '-' signs are inserted? Justify your answer by giving clear reasoning.

**b)** The natural numbers $1$,$2$,$3$,............... are partitioned into subsets $S_1=\{1\}$; $S_2=\{2,3\}$; $S_3=\{4,5,6\}$; $S_4=\{7,8,9,10\}$ and so on. What is the greatest and least numbers in the set $S_{2013}$.

Comment: That's two questions, without any indication of what effort you have done and where you face difficulty.  Better to post them separately and also show your efforts.

Comment: i think the first question is possible but donot know about second question'

Comment: I think you should read the answer posted and think why it is correct, and why the first question is "not possible" (and I just saw someone answered the second part,let me read it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a) simply look at the numbers mod 2 (classify them according to whether they are even or odd). Sum of odds is even, and sum of evens is even (and subtraction), whereas sum of odd and even is odd (or subtraction). Therefore, for the numbers between 1 and 2013 you will get an odd result, thus not 0.

Answer (score 2):

For part **b**; Note that the greatest number of $S_n$ is $1+2+3+4+\cdots+n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: is it a guess or includes proof

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula. This is easily proved by induction if you want.

Comment: can you show the proof

Comment: it is not a guess, and it is not a proof, it is a very good hint that you could think about, and come up with your own proof.

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula: I doubt people are going to spell out every detail here. Alistair has given an answer so that you can compare it to yours. Try to write out all the elements of the set $S_{2013}$. You can easily guess it by seeing the pattern and then prove your guess by induction.

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula. To see a pattern, ask yourself: "What is the greatest element in $S_1$?", "What is the greatest element in $S_2$?", and so on.. You're bound to came up with the sum above.

Comment: ok i now understand

Answer (score 1):

**Part (a) no.** Consider the similar question for the numbers from $1$ to $5$, there are exactly three odd numbers so any placement of $+$ and $-$'s would result in an odd number, not $0$. This same explanation works for any $n$ with $n=1\mod 4$, and 2013 is one such number.

Comment: please genaralise the solution with any n=1mod 4

Comment: it is already generalized, and it shouldn't be too hard to convince yourself that this is correct,think about it. List the numbers from1 to 5, take a look, do the same with the numbers from 1 to 7, and from 1 to 9.

Comment: how is it true for any n=1 mod 4 can you prove without examples

Comment: you may prove by induction (or perhaps directly too)  that if $n$ is odd then the number of odd numbers between $1$ and $n$ inclusive is odd if and only if $n=1\mod 4$.

Comment: Sum of an odd number of odd numbers is odd.

Comment: it is not only sum we can insert '-' signs

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula $n$ is odd $\implies -n$ is odd.

Comment: i did not get  you

Comment: yeah i tried with the numbers from 1 to 5 as you suggested and found it is not zero for any arrangement of signs

Comment: @Lokesh: Robert Israel clarified it. Both -3 and 3 are odd numbers. So adding the plus or minus sign is not going to change their oddness or evenness. In other words, 'Sum of an odd number of odd numbers is odd.'